# How can I add a custom script to the Azure Self Hosted Developer Portal and get it to display on the published site?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using the Azure APIM Developer Portal - Self Hosted. I wish to add a custom script file to every page of the site. I have followed the instructions here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-add-custom-javascript-file-into-self-hosted-developer/ba-p/1627032

I have also contacted Microsoft support who just pointed me to the same article.

The script does indeed show up when in design mode but on the actual published site, the new script is not referenced in the head of the document.

Has anyone successfully added a custom script to the Developer Portal through the build process?

Comment: Please publish the developer portal again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize#publish-from-the-azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that the most current version of the developer portal is published.

[Publish from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize#publish-from-the-azure-portal):

> 1 In the Azure portal, navigate to your API Management instance.
> 2 In the left menu, under Developer portal, select Portal overview.
> 3 In the Portal overview window, select Publish.

[image]

[Publish from the administrative interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize#publish-from-the-administrative-interface)

> 1 Make sure you saved your changes by selecting the Save icon.
> 2
> In the Operations section of the menu, select Publish website. This operation may take a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks Markus but this did not work. Have you successfullt added a custom script to the self-hosted developer portal?